# Marking Stack Variables for Garbage Collection

Tags: c, pointers, memory, garbage-collection

I'm trying to learn how to implement a simple mark-and-sweep garbage collection algorithm. I'm learning by looking at the [tgc library](https://github.com/orangeduck/tgc).

I'm figuring out how to iterate through the stack to mark reachable heap allocated variables. This is done in the following lines in [tgc.c](https://github.com/orangeduck/tgc/blob/master/tgc.c#L186-#L205):

```
static void tgc_mark_stack(tgc_t *gc) {

  void *stk, *bot, *top, *p;
  bot = gc->bottom; top = &stk;

  if (bot == top) { return; }

  if (bot < top) {
    for (p = top; p >= bot; p = ((char*)p) - sizeof(void*)) {
      tgc_mark_ptr(gc, *((void**)p));
    }
  }

  if (bot > top) {
    for (p = top; p <= bot; p = ((char*)p) + sizeof(void*)) {
      tgc_mark_ptr(gc, *((void**)p));
    }
  }

}
```

How does p = ((char*)p) - sizeof(void*) and p = ((char*)p) + sizeof(void*) not cause pointer p to overshoot or undershoot pointing at the correct address for the stack variable? As an example, my intuition is that we can possibly have something like this which wouldn't yield the correct heap address of char *:

```
                void *bottom ->  -----------   High address/bottom of stack
                                |           |
                                |   char a  |  1 byte
                                |           |
                                 -----------        
                                |           |
   (char*)p + sizeof(void*)  -> | char *str |  8 bytes
                                |           |
                                 ----------- 
                                |           |
                                |  int x    |  4 bytes
                                |           |
        void *p = void *top ->   ----------- 
                                |           |
                                | void *stk |  8 bytes
                                |           |
                                 -----------   Low address/top of stock
```

But I've tested this out, and the loop seems to work regardless of the stack layout. I figured that we'd do something like p = ((char*)p) - sizeof(char) which also seems to work but is a bit slower. Why does the method used in the above code work?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual addresses of variables on the stack?

Comment: It could be that all variables on the stack are aligned (in your diagram, you have a 4 byte object lying directly between two 8 byte objects; this would imply no alignment of variables in memory, which sounds unlikely). The fact that `p = ((char*)p) - sizeof(char)` *also* works (where `sizeof(char) != sizeof(void*)`) but is slower may imply that there are misaligned accesses that happen to be handled cleanly in the environment you're currently running in? Anyone correct me if either of those ideas sounds incorrect. Regardless, definitely look at the actual addresses like @rici suggested

Comment: I printed out the addresses of the stack variables as recommended, and I saw that there is some padding that occurs which causes all the stack addresses of pointer values to be a multiple of 8 bytes. Because the author initially sets p to point at a pointer which itself is 8-byte aligned, the update rule p = ((char*)p) - sizeof(void*) in the loop will be able to find all other pointers on the stack which are also 8-byte aligned! Thank you guys for the tips!